# Wrong result from statement with rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some trouble with a generated SQL statement from Hibernate. I want to get all user with their birthday within a given time range or at a specific day. While the statement for a specific day work fine, the other one just returns the first n users, where n is the number of correct users.

Considering this data:

```
ID     name      birthdate
1      firstUser 12.07.1990
2      user1     25.04.2007
3      user2     15.05.1992
4      user3     01.04.1988
```

First the generated statement for a specific day:

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        distinct *
    from
        USERS user0_ 
    where
        calculateNextBirthday(user0_.birthDate) = TO_DATE('25.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    order by
        user0_.id asc ) 
where
    rownum <= ?; // This will be the row count of this statement with the same where clause, i.e. 1 if there is only 1 matching user
```

As I said this statement returns the correct user (user1 with ID `2`).

The same statement with a between:

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        distinct *
    from
        USERS user0_ 
    where
        calculateNextBirthday(user0_.birthDate) between TO_DATE('01.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy') and TO_DATE('30.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    order by
        user0_.id asc ) 
where
    rownum <= ?; // This will be the row count of this statement with the same where clause, i.e. 1 if there is only 1 matching user
```

This statment has a strange behavior. If I execute the inner select statement, the result contains the correct users (`user1`). But executing the whole statement it will return the first user (`firstUser` with ID `1`). Changing the date like this:

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        distinct *
    from
        USERS user0_ 
    where
        calculateNextBirthday(user0_.birthDate) between TO_DATE('01.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy') and TO_DATE('30.06.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    order by
        user0_.id asc ) 
where
    rownum <= ?; // This will be the row count of this statement with the same where clause, i.e. 1 if there is only 1 matching user
```

will return the first two users (`firstUser` and `user1`), because there two matching users (`user1` and `user2`)

And if I remove the rownum from where outer statement it returns only the correct users (example below returns `user1`).

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        distinct *
    from
        USERS user0_ 
    where
        calculateNextBirthday(user0_.birthDate) between TO_DATE('01.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy') and TO_DATE('30.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    order by
        user0_.id asc )
```

So I have no idea where Oracle gets the first user entry.

Am I doing something wrong here or is there a bug in Oracle Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0?

Comment: rownum is ambiguous - it is apparently coming from the inner select

Comment: @Randy How can rownum be applied to the inner select? Especially since it works with equal.

Comment: Added some more details. I hope it will help to understand my problem. And the rownumber has the correct number. I do not want more rows I want the correct ones.

Comment: What you're doing seem to work correctly in my 11.2.0.4 environment and [in an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6a5f6/1). Also tried it with slightly different data, [which also works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90f45b/1). Which version and patch level of Oracle are you using? And can you create a reproducible example, preferably in another SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Ok my mistake it is older than I thought. It is 10.2. Also I try to create an example with SQL Fiddle.

Comment: If you're on an unpatched version of 10gR2 then a bug is more likely. You can check on My Oracle Support - though I guess you don't have a support contract. I don't have a version that old to try to recreate this I'm afraid. What you are doing *should* work. I still don't see why you have the distinct or subquery or rownum at all though - why aren't you just running the inner query anyway?

Comment: Thanks anyways. This statements are generated by hibernate when I use Criteria API. Right now I have no idea why it wrappes the statement.

Comment: It really looks like a bug in Oracle 10. If I am using a function call in this between statement, it does not filter any rows. But if I put the content of the function into the statement it returns the correct data. I tried the same statement with the function in Oracle 11 with the same values and it did work. But still I could not find any issue report or anything similar to this behavior, so I don't what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me (11g).  I don't use your calculateNextBirthday function though:

```
SQL> drop table t_users
Table dropped.
SQL> create table t_users
(
id number,
name varchar2(100),
birthdate date
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into t_users (id,name,birthdate) values (1,'firstUser',to_date('12.07.1990','DD.MM.YYYY'))
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t_users (id,name,birthdate) values (2,'user1',to_date('25.04.2007','DD.MM.YYYY'))
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t_users (id,name,birthdate) values (3,'user2',to_date('15.05.1992','DD.MM.YYYY'))
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t_users (id,name,birthdate) values (4,'user3',to_date('01.04.1988','DD.MM.YYYY'))
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select
    * 
from
    ( select
        distinct *
    from
        t_users user0_ 
    where
        to_date( to_char(birthdate, 'DD.MM') || '.' || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY' ) between TO_DATE('01.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy') and TO_DATE('30.04.2018', 'dd.MM.yyyy')
    order by
        user0_.id asc ) 
where
    rownum <= 2

        ID
----------
NAME                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BIRTHDATE
---------
         2
user1                                                                           
25-APR-07

         4
user3                                                                           
01-APR-88


2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on rownum in this situation because the order by is in the inner select. Rownum is being determined before, and therefore overriding, the order by. It's not a great practice to rely on rownum in general.

*With the caveat that I know Oracle SQL and am not inherently familiar with Hibernate, my suggestion is the following*:

I would consider creating a view with the information you need and seeing if Hibernate handles that better, otherwise I would try to override the Hibernate generated SQL statement with one that just uses the inner select, because there isn't an Oracle reason to wrap that select with the outer statement.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct. This is the correct pattern - order in the inner query, use `rownum` in the outer query. [This is explained in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.html).

Comment: Oracle documentation unfortunately doesn't always reflect real world usage. I agree in theory that this should work as written, but the author says it does not in practice, and my experience has shown that relying on rownum can cause issues like this.